# Is it possible to create Angular Application in Azure without App Service Plan?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-app-service-plans

One of our clients uses Azure for custom app development. They mentioned that they use API App for the backend and Angular front end. The front end doesn't use App Service Plan. Can anyone shed the light on how Angular front end could be implemented without the use of App Service Plan and I assume without Web App component?

Answer (score 0):

A front end application could be hosted directly from an Azure Storage Account if you enable your storage container for public access, however Your URL will look something like `http://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/`.

Alternatively, you could use an Azure CDN with a storage account as the CDN source.  You can even specify a custom domain for a CDN so if looks more professional.

For more info on storage accounts, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction

For more info on Azure CDN, visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-overview

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what the other person said, because that wont work for any real website.

You can use a VMs, containers, Azure Container Instances, Azure Functions, Azure Logic App, Azure Api App (the latest 3 require app service plan though) and probably something else. But these are the most common ways